# Copy entire node of an XML without 'xmlns="" '

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-namespaces

I have the following XML (file: `emcsh.xml`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="tohtml.xsl"?>
...
<root>
  <el>
    <d>Some text with <kbd>code</kbd> and <em>prose</em>.</d>
  </el>
</root>
```

with the following transformation (file: `tohtml.xsl`):

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<xsl:stylesheet
  version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
...
<xsl:template match="d">
  <xsl:copy-of select="node() | @*"/>
</xsl:template>
...
<xsl:if test="d">
  <div class="tipper">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="d"/>
  </div>
</xsl:if>
```

After processing files with the following pipe:

```
$ xsltproc tohtml.xsl emcsh.xml > emcsh.html && xmllint --format emcsh.html -o emcsh.html
```

the resulting string is:

```
...
<div class="tipper">
  Some text with <kbd xmlns="">code</kbd> and <em xmlns="">prose</em>.
</div>
...
```

Almost perfect, but how can I do the transformation without the empty attribute `xmlns=""`?

Thanks.

Comment: Please show us minimal but complete samples to allow us to reproduce the problem, we need to see any namespace declarations in the input and the stylesheet.

Comment: In general those undeclarations `xmlns=""` happen when you put an element in no namespace (like your `d` element from the input) into an element in a certain namespace (I guess your `div` element is put into some namespace by a namespace declaration in the stylesheet that you haven't shown). To fix that you need to decide whether you want all elements in no namespace or in a certain namespace, if you want a namespace and your input element are in no namespace then your templates need to add that namespace.

Comment: @MartinHonnen Improved examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because the default namespace of your XSLT is `http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml` and that means that literal elements (like that `<div>` there)  will be in that namespace.

When it copies the `<kbd>`, which is in a null namespace, it inserts `xmlns=""` to indicate the change in namespace.

The only way to keep the `http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml` default namespace and not have `xmlns=""` in the output is to have the XSLT convert the input elements to the `http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml` namespace.

You can do so like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<xsl:stylesheet
  version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
...
<xsl:template match="d">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="d//*">
  <xsl:element name="{local-name()}" namespace="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
...
<xsl:if test="d">
  <div class="tipper">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="d"/>
  </div>
</xsl:if>
```

Comment: @ReverendoAsperso I had thought you provided insufficient information and forgot to undo the downvote when I read it more carefully. Sorry about that. I've upvoted now. For future reference, it's best if you can provide a complete XML and XSLT that demonstrate the issue instead of abbreviated examples. See the [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) page for more info.